# How do I create a 3x3 matrix of Images with a letter at the beginning of each line?

Tags: graphics, floats, journal-publishing

While getting back into Latex for my Master thesis, I have a repetitive pattern of microscopy images that need to be arranged in 3 lines (with designated sample "names") and 3 columns, which I thought should be doable in Latex like in Powerpoint (see image). 
With using individual images to import and placing them in one figure as subfigures was no problem at all, but placing the names (A,B,C) in their position caused me to use a minipage-approach where i created a minipage for each name and image but spread the 3 lines apart across a whole page and I could not manage to position the names as intended. 
Does someone have an idea what strategy to use here in general? I have the feeling I am getting into the wrong directions and start beating a dead horse quite quickly. Eventually this would be useful for later work on writing papers, so help would be more than appreciated :-)

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Envisioned Figure]

Comment: Did you try using the  `floatrow` package? It defines a `subfloatrow` environment, and a `capposition=beside` key.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please consider posting a minimal working example with your question; it makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me just repeat my [above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528736/how-do-i-create-a-3x3-matrix-of-images-with-a-letter-at-the-beginning-of-each-li#comment1337212_528736).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begingroup
\newcommand{\InclGr}[1]{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,valign=t]{#1}}%
\begin{tabular}{c@{~}*3{@{}c}}
A & \InclGr{example-image-duck} & \InclGr{example-image-duck} & \InclGr{example-image-duck}\\
B & \InclGr{example-image-duck} & \InclGr{example-image-duck} & \InclGr{example-image-duck}\\
C & \InclGr{example-image-duck} & \InclGr{example-image-duck} & \InclGr{example-image-duck}\\
\end{tabular}\endgroup
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You need nothing special:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % also loads graphicx

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\makebox[1em][l]{A}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\hspace{1pt}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\hspace{1pt}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\\
\makebox[1em][l]{B}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\hspace{1pt}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\hspace{1pt}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\\
\makebox[1em][l]{C}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\hspace{1pt}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\hspace{1pt}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}

\caption{The global caption\label{label}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The trick is `valign=t`, to obtain top alignment with respect to the letters.

Why `1pt`? Because it's the default value of `\lineskip`.

[image]

A possible alternative with no space between the images and the block of images centered without keeping the letters into account.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % also loads graphicx

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}

\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1em][l]{A}}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\\
\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1em][l]{B}}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}\\
\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1em][l]{C}}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-1x1}

\caption{The global caption\label{label}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the issue realy easily :-)